# why command is not executing on local player

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking, unet

I am getting very strange behavior, if my player instantiate as host (Server+Player) then my command function runs perfectly and certain object become instantiate but if I join the host then my Command doesn't execute on my local player but runs on all other clients.

```
void Start()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("It is VR Player spawn-Start");
        SetVRLocalPlayerSetting();
        //InstantiateMimicVRHeadAndController();
        CmdInstantiateMimicVRHeadAndController();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("It is not vr Player its not isLocalPlayer");
        DisableSelectedMonobevaiourScripts();
    }
}
[Command]//This function have a problem
public void CmdInstantiateMimicVRHeadAndController() { 
    Debug.Log("instantiateing the controller and head object");
    vrHeadCopyObj = (GameObject) Instantiate(vrHeadObjPrefab);
    vrRightCtrlCopyObj = (GameObject) Instantiate(vrRightCtrlPrefab);
    vrLeftCtrlCopyObj = (GameObject) Instantiate(vrLeftCtrlPrefab);

    // spawn the bullet on the clients
    NetworkServer.Spawn(vrHeadCopyObj);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(vrRightCtrlCopyObj);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(vrLeftCtrlCopyObj);     
}
```

Comment: other means the server.no i dont have any other player. I just make a demo and find that command only runs on server not on other client or local player

Comment: Ah, I'm completely off-base on this one. Anyway I've found this, maybe it'll help: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/scripts-with-islocalplayer-as-child-game-object-always-return-false.372368/